# Deserializing a class with readObject() and "subsititute" the instance you called it from with the one returned by readObject

Tags: java, serialization, instance

Normally, when you deserialize a class, you have to create a separate instance for it:

```
try (ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(myFile));){
                TestClass tc = (TestClass)objectInputStream.readObject();
                myIndex = tc.getValues();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

My question is: if you called this from a TestClass instance (this), could you instead of creating a separate instance, turn "this" into the instance returned by readObject()? If not, could you somehow copy its fields without getting them individually?

Answer (score 0):

What about implementing a variation of this:

```
package clonetester;

import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

class Deserialized
{
    Integer field;    
    static Replaceble getDeserialized() //throws CloneNotSupportedException
    {
        // Specify serialized object location to be read
        File myFile = new File("<parent>","<child>");
        try
        {
            ObjectInputStream objectInputStream =
                    new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(myFile));
            return (Replaceble) objectInputStream.readObject()/*.clone()*/;
        }
        catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

class Replaceble extends Deserialized
{

    Replaceble that;
    Replaceble()
    {
        that = getDeserialized();
        if (that == null)
        {
            that = this;
        }        
    }

    // Instead of using this, use that
    // ...

    void save()
    {
        // Specify serialized object location to be written
        File myFile = new File("<parent>","<child>");
        try
        {
            ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream =
                new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(myFile));

            objectOutputStream.writeObject(that);

        }
        catch (IOException e) {}
    }

}
```

Since object references are opaque in Java, without direct manipulation, the reference that is assigned to 'this' in Your question would need to point to a clone of the serialized object You are restoring, so I cannot figure out how implement this sort of redefining the reference assigned to 'this' by only using Java. By implementing Cloneable interface, some sort of reassigning fields from the restored serialized object may be considered.